# How to extract functionvariables

Tags: r

In R I have a function. I want to extract some variables in this function

```
get <- function() {
ra <- sample(2:23,1)
}
```

Say I want to get the value `ra` then I type `get$ra` but R gives me this error-message:

```
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.
```

I want to get `ra` as a variable so I can use it in my further calculations.

Comment: Perhaps `body(get)[[2]][3]`

Comment: Why don't you `return(ra)` inside your function?

Comment: Using return(ra) wont let me have it as a variable.

Comment: Since `ra` has a fixed value and does not depend on any inputs, you could maybe achieve your goal using a list: `get <- list(ra = sample(2:23,1))`. You can then use `get$ra`, as you requested.

Comment: What is the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: ra <- get() gives me ra but I need a more general solution. Say I had more variables in the function then I should get the varible I need for the specific case.

Comment: Can't you return list of variables than?

Comment: How should one do that?

Comment: By 'list(ra)' simply don't solve the problem. I want to extract 'ra' as a variable not just get the value.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, sorry.

Comment: Can you than show an example which shows the real difference between extracting something 'as a variable' and as a value?

Comment: In a data.frame or a matrix I can extract a variable by typing data$variable. How can I do that with a function ?

Comment: By typeing data$variable you extract a column of a matrix or data.frame. Your function does not return any data.frame, so what is the problem? I don't understand you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this possibly what you're after? (too long for a comment):

```
set.seed(1)
get <- function() {
  list(ra=sample(2:23,1),somethingelse=sample(1:10,1))
}
```

Our function returns a names list, with `ra` and `somethingelse`. You can access by name using code like this:

```
get()$ra
#[1] 7
get()$somethingelse
#[1] 10
```

Or by assigning the whole list to a variable.

```
test <- get()
test
# $ra
# [1] 6
# 
# $somethingelse
# [1] 9
```